# Problem 404 with linking theme files in Wordpress when creating your own theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I create my own theme for Wordpress. I have linked the photos as indicated in the official documentation, but I get an error. Pictures are in place. In addition, I get an error from the browser console, which I put below. I will be grateful for your help

This is my code.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/images/kontakt.jpg' ); ?>" alt="" class="rounded contact__img">
```

And this is a message from the browser. But I don't understand what's going on.

'[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contained both removed whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`) characters and less-than characters (`<`) are blocked. Please remove newlines and encode less-than characters from places like element attribute values in order to load these resources. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968 for more details.'

Comment: The browser dislikes that you have code embedded in the `<img src=` line. Assuming that's a relative link, can you just replace the line with `img src="assets/images/kontakt.jpg"...`?

Comment: I tried, but without a positive result. Only the picture frame appeared. But the image itself does not load.

Comment: OK, I added a picture, give the path to the uploads folder. But that doesn't explain why WP built-in functions don't work.